# Can AFNetworking handle a queue of requests?

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

My example on iOS 6:

- 10  Multi-Part requests need to be sent (in order) to the server.
  (so the request forms a queue)
- progress should be shown.
- if one request fails all following should fail
- a request queue should be cancellable

Can AFNetworking help me with this? Or should I try to build something with NSOperations and run the loops myself?

If I need to pass context data between theses requests for example a transaction id produced by the first request. Are there any considerations about thread visibility I need to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFNetworking can do this. I recommend that you use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (which itself uses NSOperation), rather than AFHTTPSessionManager.  There are ways to do it with AFHTTPSessionManager, but none as elegant as with operations.

Under the hood, here's what you'd do without the manager:

You will use a request serializer to make your NSMutableURLRequest (for example, `[AFHTTPRequestSerializer -multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:error:]`; there's a similar JSON request serializer too).

Once you have a URL Request, make the operation with `[AFHTTPRequestOperation -initWithRequest:]`.  You should also set its completion blocks.

Finally, add your operation to `[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue` and `start` it.

---

Now that you understand how this is basically all working together, here's a simpler approach:

- Subclass  `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, optionally setting the `requestSerializer` if you don't like the default
- Override (or copy with new implementation) `-POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:success:failure:]` - what you want to do is NOT `start` your operation right away.
- Set the NSOperation dependency chains
- `start` the first one

Comment: so if I set [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1 I wouldn't even need NSOperation chains.

Comment: Yes, assuming that you add them to the queue in the correct order.

Comment: This might also be helpful http://samwize.com/2013/03/02/queue-http-operations-with-afnetworking/

Comment: When using AFNetworking 3.0: you will need to subclass AFHTTPSessionManager and no need to setMaxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 since it is already set 1 as default. Good luck.

Comment: @OhadM in my application there is requirement to cache document at a time there will be 10 document. How to cache all the document with AFNetworking 3.0 without operation queue ?

Comment: @SeemaSharma, if you need to cache files I am not sure how a 3rd party for networking will help you.