# How-to combine AFNetworking 2.0 with reactive cocoa to chain a queue of requests together?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, reactive-cocoa

I have several Requests that depend on each other and must me called in sequence?
Can somebody give me an example using AFNetworking and reactive cocoa?

Example:

1. LoginRequest (return transactionId)
2. UpdateRequest post data with transactionId
3. UploadRequest jpeg with transactionId
4. EndRequest with transactionId

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're asking for that's not covered in your last question?  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088186/can-afnetworking-handle-a-queue-of-requests)

Comment: sure. Since my real use case is more complex I wonder if add reactive cocoa maybe my code becomes more expressive and clearer. In the pure NSOperation Queue example I have some problems passing context from one NSOperation to the next because So maybe reactive cocoa can help me here? what do you think?

Comment: I am actually looking for some example reactive code to get me started?

Comment: There's lots of sample code in their README and in the NSHipster article. Have you read that?

Comment: the read me yes the NSHipster not. I'll try to find it... could you send me some links?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1hJE5oa

Comment: this is the best example so far that i was able to find http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/managing-nested-asynchronous-callbacks-in-objective-c-using-reactive-cocoa/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method names are clearly made-up but should give you a sense of the form of the code you'd write:

```
[[self 
    executeLoginRequest] 
    flattenMap:^(id transactionId) {
        return [[[self 
            executeUpdateRequest:data withTransactionId:transactionId] 
            then:^{
                return [self executeUploadRequest:jpeg withTransactionId:transactionId];
            }] 
            then:^{
                return [self endRequests:transactionId];
            }];
    }]
```

We're using `-flattenMap:` to take the result of the login request and then make more requests off of it.

Comment: that is what I am looking for. I have of sequence of data-items that each need to be handed to executeUploadRequest (so executeUploadReques  is exected on each item in the sequence). how can I inject this sequence into the above code?(Kind of a loop around flattenMap)

Comment: maybe I just need  to inject another signal which produces many executeUpdateRequest signals and flattenMap into the above?

Comment: Ha .... I just need to use recursion in [self executeUploadRequest:jpeg withTransactionId:transactionId] ? am I right or not?

Comment: if I want to add an progress indicator to each request do I have to inject a doNext in-between every step?

Comment: `array.rac_sequence.signal` will give you a signal which sends each of the items in the array. You can `-flattenMap:` each of them to do whatever you need.

Comment: `-doNext:` is probably a legit place to update a progress indicator.