# iOS Swift Preloading Application Data

Tags: ios, swift, api, core-data

I am working on an application that is dependent on data that should be loaded from our remote servers on the application first launch. Currently I simply fetch data using few different functions and then loading the data into different object arrays. I did some research about preloading data but everything I found has specifically to do with preloading data using CoreData objects. Here are my questions:

1. Should I load data using CoreData objects? Is it OK to load data into arrays of custom objects?
2. What are the pros and cons of loading that data into arrays of custom objects?
3. What are the pros and cons of loading the data into CoreData objects?
4. How should I get the application to load the data, make sure each function has completed and the data has been loaded before the application moves on with loading the primary view?

Thank you!

Comment: Core Data will save the data for you so you can re-use it without having to reload it the next time your app is run. Depending on your use case, this may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants of loading data to CoreData objects and into array of custom objects are ok, but mainly serves different purposes. Storing data using CoreData objects is the most common way of storing persistent data. Thus if you might have to support offline mode work of your application in future, that's the right choice. If you know for sure that your application should work only in case Internet access is available, there is no need to support data persistence and storing data into array of custom objects is absolutely enough.

Talking about data server requests chaining. You can perform synchronous calls in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. In such case application will display launch screen while data is loading. But that's probably not the best solution because user might be confused what is happening so long period of time before application actually starts. If I were you I would rather create loading screen with some kind of progress bar that shows user that data is loading and how much data is already loaded. For chaining requests in such controller I would use [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). You can find an example of how to do so by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119078/4250188).

Comment: Unfortunately application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn't working. That is where my code is now. The problem I am having is I am using a custom pod called DropDown (https://cocoapods.org/pods/DropDown) and my default view is loaded before the datasource is complete which means the menu is empty. If I move off the default view and come back it works fine. I cannot post code because stackoverflow sucks and has a limit on comments.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: please?